# Forcing exercise from Kunen's book

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm new in the study of the forcing method and I having some troubbles to solve some of the exercise from Kunen's book (edition 2013): specifically, problem IV 2.46 from page 271. It says the following:

"Let M a ctm for ZFC and $\mathbb{P}=Fn(\omega,2)$. Prove that there exists a filter $G$ on $\mathbb{P}$ such that there is no transitive $N\supset M$ such that $N\vDash ZF-P$, $G\in N$ and $o(M)=o(N)$."

Kunen gives as a Hint that G can be code a well-order of $\omega$ of type greater than $o(M)$. So, my questions are:

- First of all, what does mean that $G$ can be code a well-order of $\omega$?
- Secondly, how we can prove that statement?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Let $\pi:\omega\times\omega\to\omega$ be any injection; the Cantor pairing function will do, or the map $\langle m,n\rangle\mapsto 2^{m+1}3^{n+1}$. Then $x\subseteq\omega$ codes a well-order on $\omega$ if $$\{\langle m,n\rangle\in\omega\times\omega:\pi(m,n)\in x\}$$ is a well-order on $\omega$.

Comment: Thank you for the aclariment @BrianM.Scott. Could you help to do the exercise?

Comment: You’re welcome. Unfortunately, I can’t help with the actual problem: it’s been many years since I did any forcing, and I’m hopelessly rusty. I suspect, though, that the hint is intended to suggest that if $G\in N$, then $o(N)>o(M)$.

Comment: @Brian: We can force you to do some forcing, and if we take a generic thing, then it will actually work. But this just means that you were forcing in the ground model. So there you have it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Have you any idea to help me? Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch: Take $x \subseteq \omega$ coding a well order on $\omega$ of order type $> o(M)$ using the coding suggested by B. Scott. Let $G = \{p \in Fn(\omega, 2): p \subseteq x\}$. Towards a contradiction, suppose there is some transitive model $N$ of ZF - P that extends $M$, contains $G$ and has the same ordinals as $M$. Since $G \in N$, so is $\bigcup G = x$ since $N$ models union axiom. Decode $x$ to get the well ordering that it is coding. Note that the proof of the fact that every well ordered set is order isomorphic to a unique ordinal works without power set hence $N$ contains the ordinal coded by $x$. This contradicts the fact that $M$ and $N$ have the same ordinals.

Comment: Thank you @Justin for your answer. However, I don't still understand what "decode $x$ to get the well ordering" means. Could you write its meaning in a formal way? Thank you!!